# TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types when plotting a colormap in basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, colormap

I would like to draw a scatter plot about the relationship between house prices and geographic coordinates using a colormap.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


lats = df['latitude'].as_matrix()
lons = df['longitude'].as_matrix()

zoom_scale = 0

bbox = [np.min(lats)-zoom_scale,np.max(lats)+zoom_scale,\
        np.min(lons)-zoom_scale,np.max(lons)+zoom_scale]

plt.figure()

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=bbox[0],urcrnrlat=bbox[1],\
    llcrnrlon=bbox[2],urcrnrlon=bbox[3],resolution='i')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawrivers()

x,y = m(lons,lats)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
plot = m.scatter(x,y,'o',c = df['price'],cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar(plot)
plt.title("House Price with Geographic Coordinate")
plt.show()
```

The console gives a TypeError:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) in

```
     28 x,y = m(lons,lats)
     29 cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
---> 30 plot = m.scatter(x,y,'o',c = df['price'],cmap=cm)
     31 plt.colorbar(plot)
     32 plt.title("House Price with Geographic Coordinate")

....

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in set_sizes(self, sizes, dpi)
    872             self._sizes = np.asarray(sizes)
    873             self._transforms = np.zeros((len(self._sizes), 3, 3))
--> 874             scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor
    875             self._transforms[:, 0, 0] = scale
    876             self._transforms[:, 1, 1] = scale
```

TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

How can I solve this?
Best regards

Comment: in the line `plot = m.scatter(x,y,'o',c = df['price'],cmap=cm)`, what is the content of `df['price']`? If you run the code without `c = df['price']` does it work?

Comment: I intended to plot the house price of each coordinates and see whether there will be any relationships between them. If i delete the c = df [ 'price' ] and the cmap setting, the console still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try without the 'o', that is not necessary in a `scatter`.

Answer (score 3):

Take out the `'o'` from `plt.scatter` line.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with `scatter` plots. This can be solved by explicitly mentioning what parameters are you providing.

So, change

```
plot = m.scatter(x,y,'o',c = df['price'],cmap=cm)
```

to

```
plot = m.scatter(x,y,marker='o',cmap=cm)
```

---

**Some tips for free**: Whenever using scatter plots, avoid naming function parameters directly i.e.,

```
plt.scatter(x,y,'blue')
```

Rather use

```
plt.scatter(x,y,color='blue')
```

Also, to include debugging in your daily programming, begin with simply plotting the scatter as `plot = m.scatter(x,y)`. Then, go on increasing the attributes like color, shape, etc.

**Note**: This error is not prone in line plots (`plt.plot(x,y,'red')` will work)